# Do defensive weapon strap-ons only take effect depending on which weapon (melee/ranged) I'm holding?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

For example, I have a melee weapon with the 'Iron Crossguard' defensive strap-on (deflect 15% more damage when you block):

[image: 'Iron Crossguard' defensive strap-on (deflect 15% more damage when you block)]

And in combat, I attacked with my ranged weapon, so I'm now holding my ranged weapon. If I get attacked while holding the ranged weapon, will I still deflect 15% more damage when I block?

Comment: Am I the only one who thought of Se7en when I read "weapon strap-on"?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not holding the weapon that the strap-on is...well...strapped on to when you are attacked then no the perk will not take affect and reduce the damage. Just like how if you have a bonus fire strap-on on your ranged weapon the perk does not take affect when you use your melee weapon. I would suggest using that strap-on on what ever weapon you have out the majority of the time.

Comment: source​​​​​​​​?

Comment: experience...does that count for nothing on this site half the time anymore?

Comment: It does for things that are obvious, but this is something you can't normally see.  To be sure, you'd have to go out of your way to actively do some testing.

Comment: I've used the strap-ons and put a lot of time into that game so far. This concept is very similar to a lot of RPG games. One I'm currently working on is the Witcher 2, extremely simialar weapon enchancement concept, just cannot remove the enhancements in the Witcher 2.

Answer (score -2):

I didn't try with the defensive strap ons, but the offensive ones do not apply to both weapons.

I spent the majority of the game with bleeding attached to my ranged weapon, since I used ones that hit multiple targets.  My melee weapon, sadly, did not cause them to bleed when I Roshambo'ed them to start the fight.

Comment: You probably didn't get the bleeding from Roshambo because you weren't actually using a melee WEAPON, you simply did a melee ATTACK. If you'd gone in with a sword and hit them then you'd get your bleeding strap on.